# How to make method return type covariant

Tags: scala

I have a following classes:

```
trait Foo {
  def update: Foo
}

class ConcreteFoo extends Foo {
  override def update: Foo = new ConcreteFoo
}


class FooManager[T <: Foo](val foos: mutable.Map[String, T]) {

  def update(id: String): Unit = {
    foos.update(id, foos(id).update)
  }

}
```

And of course `update` function does not compiles:

> Type missmatch found Foo required T

How to make `def update: Foo` covariant?

Comment: Mutable Maps are invariant by design. You can't really make `FooManager` covariant when you're using mutable Maps.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like you want something like F-bounded polymorphism:

```
trait Foo[T <: Foo[T]] { self: T =>
  def update: T
}

class ConcreteFoo extends Foo[ConcreteFoo] {
  override def update = new ConcreteFoo
}


class FooManager[T <: Foo[T]](val foos: mutable.Map[String, T]) {

  def update(id: String): Unit = {
    foos.update(id, foos(id).update)
  }

}
```

---

An alternative, and probably simpler, solution is to use an immutable `Map`, as Luka said. But then there's no need to have type parameters anymore:

```
trait Foo {
  def update: Foo
}

class ConcreteFoo extends Foo {
  override def update: Foo = new ConcreteFoo
}


class FooManager(private var _foos: immutable.Map[String, Foo]) {

  def foos = _foos

  def update(id: String): Unit = {
    _foos = _foos.updated(id, _foos(id).update)
  }   
}
```

You could also keep your current solution and remove the type parameter. But then you have the slight inconvenience that you can't pass a `mutable.Map[String,ConcreteFoo]` to the constructor of `FooManager`.

Answer (score 3):

I'd suggest going with an immutable Map instead. As only immutable collections can have covariant type parameters.

```
class FooManager[+T <: Foo](val foos: immutable.Map[String, T]) {

  def update(id: String): FooManager[Foo] = {
    new FooManager(foos.updated(id, foos(id).update))
  }

}
```

Comment: I think that if you make it immutable you should just remove the type parameter of `FooManager`.

Comment: Yeah, true. Edited!

Comment: `update ` is method of `Foo`, so edit was wrong(first variant was right), sorry for method name confusing. Yes, this solution is right way, but i can't change update protocol to `def update(id: String): FooManager[Foo]`. Only way - is reassing foos to new collection after updating, but `var foos: immutable.Map[String, T]` make code uncompiled with `covariant type T occurs in contravariant position`. So Jasper-M's answer more suitable for me.